# ASP.NET C# treeview how to fire SelectedNodeChanged event programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a treeview on an `.aspx` page, when I mouse click on the tree node, the `treeview_selectedNodeChange` event works fine, but when I try to select a node programmatically, it does not fire the `treeview_selectedNodeChange` event. Does anybody have a solution?

This is the treeview design in .aspx:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" HoverNodeStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
     OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" ImageSet="Arrows" 
     ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" Font-Bold="True" />
    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px"
               NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px"></NodeStyle>
    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" HorizontalPadding="0px"
             VerticalPadding="0px" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

This is how I select a node programmatically in c#:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes)
{
    if (node.Value == "2")
    {
        node.Selected = true;
        node.Select();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(null, null);` before your break statement. This will trigger the TreeView event.